# list files not matching *mov* using dir command in XP

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

If I do in XP command line:

```
dir d:\*mov*
```

I get a list of files contaning mov, move, Moving etc.  How do I get the opposite, files not containing *mov*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see aking1012's response and I raise him...

```
dir d:\* /a-d | find /v /i "mov"
```

The restriction on the dir command hides directories and the /i parameter on the find ignores case.

Comment: good points +1...

Answer (score 1):

this might do the trick:
dir d:\* | find /v mov